# How to convert a mac address to oui lookup format

Tags: java, mac-address

I have a `mac address` in the format of `80:ad:16:c5:a6:28`, now in my `oui` database downloaded mac vendors are having mac id's starting from `0` to `16580522`.

So the question:

> how do I convert my mac address to match mac address in the database?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a few entries in your database including the vendor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the first 3 bytes of the mac address and convert hex to decimal.

```
String mac = "80:ad:16:c5:a6:28";
String[] byteStr = mac.split(":");
int identifier = Integer.parseInt(byteStr[0],16) * 256 * 256 + Integer.parseInt(byteStr[1],16) * 256 + Integer.parseInt(byteStr[2],16);
```